# VBA Paste Range

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please:

I'm using the code below (which I've had some help with) to copy rows of data from one sheet to another if a given range of cells match a secific formula result.

```
Sub test()
    Set Sht = Sheets("Sheet 1")
    rw = 5
    Do While Len(Sht.Cells(rw, "A").Value) > 0
        If Sht.Cells(rw, "B").Value > 0 Then
            ResourcesAllUsed = True
            For colm = 3 To 25 Step 2
                If (Sht.Cells(rw, colm + 1).Value < (Sht.Cells(rw, colm).Value * 0.85)) Or (Sht.Cells(rw, colm + 1 + 25).Value < (Sht.Cells(rw, colm + 25).Value * 0.85)) Then
                    ResourcesAllUsed = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next colm
            If Not ResourcesAllUsed Then
                With Sheets("Sheet 2")
                    NextRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Cells(NextRw, "A").Resize(, 26).Value = Sht.Cells(rw, "A").Resize(, 26).Value
                    .Cells(NextRw, "AD").Value = Sht.Cells(rw, "AD").Value
                End With
            End If
        End If
        rw = rw + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```

The copy works fine, but I'm having a little trouble with the row in which to start pasting from.

I'd like to start pasting from "A5" but for some reason, the paste starts at "A2".

I just wondered whether someone may be able to look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NextRow` variable is set to A2 the first time through the loop, which means the only data is in A1 (or there's nothing in A1 either). To force it to start in A5, you could change the line to:

```
NextRw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1,5)
```

This would mean you'd have blank cells in rows 2 (or 1) through 4.

Comment: Hi @Doug Clancy, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post. Your solution works great.

All the best and kind regards